# Вопросы по Select

Tags: sql, sql-server

Дана таблица:

```
create table dbo.statistics 
(login    varchar(64),
send_date date, 
sms_cnt   int )
```

Нужно *написать запрос, возвращающий для каждого логина минимальную дату, когда количество сообщений было максимально, и максимальную дату, когда количество сообщений было минимально, а также количество сообщений.*

```
Ожидаемый результат:
| login | min_date | max_sms_cnt | max_date |min_sms_cnt |
+-------+----------+-------------+----------+------------+
|login1 | 20150411 | 15154       | 20151012 | 10         |
|login2 | 20150301 | 20          | 20160513 | 8          |
```

Мой запрос, правильно ли:

```
select 
      [login], min(send_date) mindate, max(sms_cnt) maxcnt,
      max(send_date) maxdate, min(sms_cnt) mincnt
from [dbo].[statistics] (nolock)
```

2-й вопрос *Написать запрос, возвращающий логины(login) и суммарный трафик(sms_cnt) всех логинов, которые рассылались более 7 дней.*

Мой скрипт правильно ли:

```
select 
      [login], sum([sms_cnt]) [total]
from  [dbo].[statistics] (nolock)
where [send_date] < dateadd(day,-7,getdate())
group by [login]
order by 2
```

Если неправильно помогите пжл с запросами как правильно)

Comment: 1. абсолютно не правильно. 2. не правильно, если я год назад отправил 1 sms, то ваш запрос это покажет, потому что ранее, чем 7 дней назад она прошла. а вам нужны те, кто рассылали более 7 дней (правда я не понимаю точно что требуется, может достаточно получить разницу между минимальной и максимальной датой, а может проверить, что рассылки были в не менее чем 7 разных дней)

Comment: @Mike, по второму так будет правильно ?                                          select 
      [login], sum([sms_cnt]) [total], count( [login])
from  [dbo].[statistics] (nolock)
group by [login]
having count( [login])>7
order by 2

Comment: Хотя не понятно что лежит в таблице statistics. надо обязательно указывать уникальные ключи и содержится ли время в колонки даты ... Вы и правы с просто count(), если на пользователя за день там гарантированно одна запись

Answer (score 0):

1)

```
select *
from 
(select distinct login 
 from dbo.[statistics] ) as l
 outer apply(select top(1)  [send_date],[sms_cnt] from  dbo.[statistics] 
             where login = l.[login] order by sms_cnt desc, send_date asc ) as max
 outer apply(select top(1)  [send_date],[sms_cnt] from  dbo.[statistics] 
             where login = l.[login] order by sms_cnt asc,  send_date desc ) as min
```

2)

```
select 
      [login], sum([sms_cnt]) [total], count( [login])
from  [dbo].[statistics] (nolock)
group by [login]
having count( [login])>7
order by 2
```